# One-line code in bashrc to edit pdf

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to have a one-line code in bashrc, for removing the first page of a pdf. The command to be typed in the bash prompt could of the form:

> cut_command name.pdf

This command should remove the first page of name.pdf and save the remaining pages under the original file name. How should I do this? I have alias commands in bashrc and pdftk package, but I do not know how to use them together to this end.

Comment: You do realize that 'cut' conflicts with one of the core utilities, yes?

Comment: Do you mean `cut the first page and save the remainder with the original name` or do you mean `cut the first page and save it (the first page) with the original name`?

Comment: Do you have a longer command in mind already, and just need help packaging it up under the name `cut` (which, yes, you should choose a different name), or do you need help developing a command that accomplishes this task?

Comment: @TimPost: It could be any command not 'cut' necessarily; I wanted to demonstrate an example.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, help to develop such a command whose functionality could lie within bashrc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, since you have pdftk package why not run this command:

```
pdftk old.pdf cat 2-end output new.pdf && rm old.pdf && mv new.pdf old.pdf
```

this should remove the first page and save the rest.

Comment: Thanks but what do I put in my bashrc file? I want a command like cmd abc.pdf, which can do the job on the terminal.